# Checking whether the system can respond to a given URL scheme on iOS

Tags: ios

I'm trying to find a good way to check whether a certain URL scheme is registered on iOS. The use case here is that I want to check if the user has a specific app installed and if so offer functionality based on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `canOpenURL` method on `UIApplication`.  Class reference [HERE](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: I knew there would be some easy way to do this, weird that none of my searches through the docs picked this up.